# Binary Search for list but not for set

Tags: java, collections

in `Collection` it is:

```
binarySearch(List list, Object key)
```

Why is binary search not applicable for `Set`? Why is it only for `List`?

Any specific reason?

Answer (score 8):

Binary search implies a sorted container. A set is either unordered (`HashSet`), in which case a binary search cannot be performed, or it is ordered (`TreeSet`), in which case its lookup operation is already as efficient as a binary search (i.e. `O(Log2(N))`).

Answer (score 5):

Binary search works on ordered collection.
Set are not ordered.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick response. I understood from all the responses that binarySearch can be used on only ordered collection. But what if I want to use for TreeSet? Should not it be possible? Is there any alternate to search an object from the Set which is similar to binary search?

Comment: You can convert your set to an ordered collection.

Comment: A `TreeSet` may be ordered, but you can't refer to its elements by an index.

Comment: as i understand you'd like to search in TreeSet. TreeSet implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains) (dixit documentation). i think it already uses binarySearch ! (i have'nt seen the source while claiming this).

Answer (score 4):

In this case a binary search will only work if the List is ordered and sorted. i.e. it doesn't work for all lists, only ones pre sorted.

A set is not ordered and might not be sorted.

If the Set is sorted, you can use one of the methods of NavigableSet

Answer (score 3):

A set is unordered, and doesn't have indexes for the elements it contains. Therefore a binarySearch() method that returns the index of the element does not make sense.